# Handlebars helpers inside loop

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

**Template**

```
   <script id='handlebar-template'>
    {{#each tags}}
            {{#isObject this}}
                <span>Object</span>
            {{else}}
                <span>String</span>
            {{/isObject}}
    {{/each}}
   </script>
```

**Script**

```
 <script>
    Handlebars.registerHelper('isObject', function(o) {
       return typeof o === "object";
    });

    var props = {"tags": ["Google"]}
    var html = $("#handlebar-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(html);
    console.log(template(props));
</script>
```

**Output Expected**

```
<span>String</span>
```

**Actual Output**

```
false
```

`else` block is executed but the output returns is `false` instead of `<span>String</span>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using helper wrong or have a wrong helper.

In first case, change template to use `{{#if}}` helper:

```
{{#if (isObject this)}}
    <span>Object</span>
{{else}}
    <span>String</span>
{{/if}}
```

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60L0cre4/).

In second case, you need to implement `{{else}}` logic by yourself inside the helper.
Look at Handlebars block helpers documentation for [conditionals](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals).